# Is this real-valued function differentiable at $0$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Define $$y(x)=\begin{cases} x^2 & x\ge 0 \\ -x^2 & x \lt 0\end{cases}$$

I find that this function continuous at $x=0$.

However, when I try to find this function is differentiable at $x=0$:

$$ \lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{f(x+h)^2-f(x^2)}{h}  = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2xh+h^2}{h}$$

therefore

$f'(x) = 2x$ implies $f'(0)= 2\cdot 0 = 0$

$$ \lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{f-(x+h)^2-f(-x^2)}{h}  = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-2xh-h^2}{h}$$

therefore $f'(x)=-2x , f'(0) = 0$

The function is differentiable at $x=0$

Correct?

Comment: Yes; no worries.

Comment: Note that you can also write $y=x\cdot|x|$ and get $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h\cdot |h|-0}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}|h|=0$

Comment: oh,,,nice~ thanks.

Comment: Another way to see this geometrically is to note that the tangent to the parabola $y=x^2$ at $(0,0)$ is horizontal and coincides with the tangent to the reflected parabola $y=-x^2$ at the same point.

Comment: @MPW is there any possibility, when the function is not continuous at some point and then differentiable at the same point? as far as i know, it's not possible.

Comment: No. Differentiability is a stronger condition than continuity; $f$ differentiable at $x_0$ implies $f$ continuous at $x_0$. Equivalently, $f$ not continuous at $x_0$ implies $f$ not differentiable at $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function is represented by those portions of the curves occupying Quadrants I and III. The horizontal green line represents the tangent line at $(0,0), where the derivative is zero.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0+}y'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}x^2=2x=0$$$$\lim_{x\to0-}y'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}-x^2=-2x=0$$As approaching from both sides the limit is the same:$$\lim_{x\to0}y'(x)=0$$So in short, the function is differentiable at $0$ and you're correct.