# is this function differentiable at zero?

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

Define $$y(x)=\begin{cases} x^2+1 & x\ge 0 \\ -(x^2+1) & x \lt 0\end{cases}$$

I find that this function is not continuous at $x=0$.

However, when I try to find this function is differentiable at $x=0$:

and I already know that if the function is not continous at some point, also not differenciate at the same point.

but i want to know that, why is it not differentiable?

$$ \lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{f(x+h)^2-f(x^2)}{h}  = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2h+h}{h}$$

therefore (I'm stuck here.)

$f'(x) = \infty$ (since limit = 1+2/h)  or  $f'(x) = 2x$ or  $f'(x) = 3$ 
(Which one is correct?)

$$ \lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{f-(x+h)^2-f(-x^2+1)}{h}  = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h}{h}$$

therefore $f'(x) = 1$

the function is not differentiable at x = 0

Comment: rlartiga is pointing out that $f$ *is* continuous.

Comment: This question is essentially identical to your previous question. You just added $1$ to the function. So the answer is the same.

Comment: The function is one plus the function in your [earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1461016/is-this-real-valued-function-differentiable-at-0). The responses there apply to it with _extremely_ minor differences.

Comment: @HenningMakholm sorry i forgot some given...~ could you pls check again` ~

Comment: You have a lot of notation problems: is the function $y$ or $f$? and why do you write $f(x+h)^2-f(x^2)$? isn't $x$ supposed to be $0$ during your argument? also, $\frac{2h+h}{h}$ is $3$.

Comment: This whole presentation appears to be seriously confused.

Comment: sorry for that , i just want to know that how come is it not differentiable at x=0

Answer (score 1):

A function that is not even continuous at $0$ cannot be differentiable there.

Comment: thanks. could pls give me a hint how can i show that the function is not differentiable~

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking in this series of questions why a function that is not continuous at a point can't be differentiable at that point. (This function doesn't furnish an example, but I will address the idea anyway.)

The reason that differentiability implies continuity is that if the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ exists, then since the denominator converges to $0$ then at a bare minimum you must also have that the numerator converges to $0$.

Saying that $$\lim_{h\to 0}f(x+h)-f(x) = 0$$ is precisely the same as saying that $$\lim_{y\to x}f(y)-f(x) = 0$$ which is in turn precisely the same as saying that $$\lim_{y\to x}f(y) = f(x)$$ and this is precisely the statement that $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{h \to 0+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0+}\frac{h^2+1-1}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0+}2h=0$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0-}\frac{-h^2-1-1}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0-}\frac{-h^2-2}{h}$$

As you can see the second limit is undefined.